# Update the xml file on the server from the form in Sencha application

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to send data from the form and update the xml file on the server. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Thanks
Ishan jain

Answer (score 2):

Write a PHP/JSP on your server to which you will submit your form. On form submit do whatever file operation you want on the basis of received data.

Advice : Put more information if you want good answer and show [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) so far.

Comment: Thanks for your concern. I have to send data from a booking form. I have not tried much but I am trying to do using xml writer. I will post more code in some time.